# Migrate module: how to handle adding Redirects and rolling back?

Tags: redirection, migrations

I'm writing some migrations using the Migrate module. I need to set up redirects after I migrate in an item, but I'm not sure where to perform that action.

I can do it in the complete() function for the migration, which is called after each object has successfully been inserted. At that point, I'd have enough information to programmatically add a redirect.

However, if I needed to roll back the migration, I don't see where I can put in any clean up code to remove those redirects. There are pre and post rollback functions, but those are called before the entire migration is rolled back.

I suppose one alternative would be to, in a pre rollback, query the map table for all the objects and then lookup and destroy the redirects like that. Seems ugly.

I think the best solution here is to have a pre/post rollback function available on a per-object basis.

Anyone run into this previously or have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirects associated with the migrated (node) content should be automatically removed during the rollback.

Comment: Ah I was making an assumption that the redirects were not directly related to node ID's. Looks like they are! I think the question still stands on its own a bit, because there could be cases where this type of relationship doesn't exist on data you're migrating in.

Comment: This is really a comment, and not an answer.  But, since it is accepted, it should be edited to make it more answer-like.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't add a comment earlier today (not enough points). I will edit now to convert to an answer.